# Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I deployed a chaincode to a network of peers. It was unsuccessful. I looked at a peer's log and saw an error message:
Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pull a specific base image from https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage/ using `docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:<tag name>`
2. Check the image id of the downloaded image using `docker images`
3. Tag this image as latest `docker tag <imageID> latest`

Answer (score 0):

you should run 'make images' to create hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest.