# Hyperledger Docker endpoint not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, hyperledger

I have setup a 2 node Hyperledger network using Docker images on Ubuntu 14.04 by creating 2 containers as per the steps provided @ http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Network-setup/#leveraging-published-docker-images

Then I tried to deploy a chaincode, which compiles without errors, by calling POST /chaincode API and got response 200 with the hash returned for the deployed chaincode.

But immediately after that I got the following error in the docker logs:

```
08:44:26.560 [consensus/noops] processTransactions -> DEBU 053 Starting TX batch with timestamp: seconds:1473929066 nanos:560229743
08:44:26.560 [consensus/noops] processTransactions -> DEBU 054 Executing batch of 1 transactions with timestamp seconds:1473929066 nanos:560229743
08:44:26.563 [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 055 Executable is /opt/gopath/bin/1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84
08:44:26.564 [chaincode] Deploy -> DEBU 056 deploying chaincode 1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84(networkid:dev,peerid:vp0)
08:44:26.564 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 057 waiting for container(dev-vp0-1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84) lock
08:44:26.564 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 058 got container (dev-vp0-1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84) lock

**08:44:26.565 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 059 Error building images: cannot connect to Docker endpoint**
```

So how do I resolve this?

Another update. I did the following:

1) Edited /etc/default/docker to add the entry: DOCKER_OPTS="--api-cors-header='*' -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock "

2) Restarted docker

3) Started a node using docker-compose up command

Tried deploying chaincode and now I get a different error:

```
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.441 [consensus/noops] handleChannels -> DEBU 048 Process block due to time 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.441 [consensus/noops] processTransactions -> DEBU 049 Starting TX batch with timestamp: seconds:1475042973 nanos:441383619 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.441 [consensus/noops] processTransactions -> DEBU 04a Executing batch of 1 transactions with timestamp seconds:1475042973 nanos:441383619 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.446 [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 04b Executable is /opt/gopath/bin/1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.446 [chaincode] Deploy -> DEBU 04c deploying chaincode 1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84(networkid:dev,peerid:vp0) 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.446 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 04d waiting for container(dev-vp0-1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84) lock 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:33.446 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 04e got container (dev-vp0-1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84) lock 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:37.608 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 04f Touch service indicates no dropped connections 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:37.608 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 050 Connected to: [] vp0_1 | 06:09:37.608 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 051 Discovery knows about: [] 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:39.533 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 052 Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage 
    vp0_1 | 06:09:39.533 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 053 Image Output:
```

Comment: did you define the correct endpoint while creating the network ?

Comment: I am using the following <br> <br> docker-compose file vp0: image: hyperledger/fabric-peer ports: - "7050:7050" environment: - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=172.17.0.1:2375 - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG command: peer node start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your container environment variable:

```
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Make sure this file is accessible from within your container as for some reason it was not the case for me and I had to mount it.

Then if you get `deployImage -> ERRO 052 Error building images: Tag latest not found..`. it is a known issue (ex. [Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644889/error-building-images-tag-latest-not-found-in-repository-docker-io-hyperledger)).

I downloaded one of the available images and retagged it

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0 hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest
```

Comment: I had tried CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock in docker-compose but it didn't work. Does this need to be specified in some other file?

Comment: I tried specified CORE_VM_ENDPOINT and not getting ....vp0_1  | 06:02:59.119 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 05b got container (dev-vp0-1e90b51f9129b97d5312d5c24364085777602a06d40d6e2c9209b4f30d7e66facb26e956443028611539962acc6de550eba03bbb1fd0e7bbd655cb19c5a6ef84) lock
vp0_1  | 06:02:59.119 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 05c Error building images: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Comment: yep I faced the same issue, check if /var/run/docker.sock exists in your host then if ok mount it in your container -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Thanks a bunch Marc. Problem solved after pulling fabric-baseimage. Was able to deploy a chaincode and query it too !! I wonder why the documentation is still incomplete on hyperledger official site :(

Comment: A list of tags can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage/tags/