# Docker on mac error message can't connect to Docker endpoint

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have tried the vagrant devenv for multi-peers network and it worked fine. now I am trying to do the same thing on mac, but I got such err message

```
vp_1  | 07:21:42.489 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 04c Error building images: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
vp_1  | 07:21:42.489 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 04d Image Output:
vp_1  | ********************
vp_1  |
vp_1  | ********************
vp_1  | 07:21:42.553 [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 05b start-could not recreate container cannot connect to Docker endpoint
vp_1  | 07:21:42.553 [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 05c container lock deleted(dev-jdoe-04233c6dd8364b9f0749882eb6d1b50992b942aa0a664182946f411ab46802a88574932ccd75f8c75e780036e363d52dd56ccadc2bfde95709fc39148d76f050)
vp_1  | 07:21:42.553 [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 05d launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
```

Belowing is my compose file,

```
vp:
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
ports:
- "5000:5000"
environment:
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:2375
- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
command: peer node start
```

I have tried assigning endpoint to 
"unix:///var/run/docker.sock" and it appear the other err message as belowing

```
vp_1  | 07:39:39.642 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 045 Error building images: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
vp_1  | 07:39:39.642 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 046 Image Output:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT` set to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, please make sure that `var/run/docker.sock` exists in your host. please mount it if its not exist.

Also, refer to the following question, [Hyperledger Docker endpoint not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715586/hyperledger-docker-endpoint-not-found/39727185#39727185)